# Can I set access rights to custom pages?

Tags: custom-page

Can we add/remove access for users to Tridion Custom Pages?
Is there a possibility where I can decide which user can see which custom page, or which user can only see the custom pages? I tried to use the Properties of Custom Pages, but it looks disabled - have attached the screenshot.

[image: Custom Page properties]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see any standard way to apply security to custom pages. Thinking about that, maybe it could be made a GUI Extension to use the logged user or group, with some property extension on the custom page configuration.

Comment: Thanks  Raúl. Will check on these lines, I thought it's easy if Tridion provides anything like that.

Answer (score 7):

No, there is no built-in option to secure a custom page via Tridion itself (i.e. to its users and groups). Some might say that this makes sense, as a custom page is really just a URL that is loaded in an iframe, so if you know the URL then you can probably by-pass Tridion anyway.

Of course, if you're hosting your custom page within the same system/environment as the Tridion web site then you can probably implement the same authentication system (integrated authentication, SSO etc, whatever) as a basic check. You could perhaps even check whether the user is a member of a specific group in Tridion, but it would still essentially be custom code running within the context of your custom page.

Comment: +1 - Back in the day I remember using Windows groups to control access to the folders where the custom pages were deployed. This coupled with a proper error page for people with no access gave the users an "OK" way to manage access.